# lxml is not coercing int into a string before parsing it

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to pull a Qualys vulnerability report ID from an API call with python. Essentially, the report ID is an `int`, and lxml can only parse strings. I have used my same code in the past to do this and it worked fine. I assumed `lxml` is smart enough to coerce the `int` into a `string` before parsing. Is there any way I can do this manually so I stop getting parse errors? Below is my code, output, and the traceback.

`Code:`

```
import requests
import time
import lxml
from lxml import etree

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update({'X-Requested-With':'X'})

def login(s):
    payload = {'action':'login', 'username':'X', 'password':'X'}

    r = s.post('https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/session/', 
    data=payload)

def launchReport(s, polling_delay=250):
    payload = {'action':'launch', 'template_id':'X', 
    'output_format':'xml', 'report_title':'X'}

    r = s.post('https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/fo/report/', 
    data=payload)
    print r.text
    extract_id = etree.XML(r).find('.//VALUE')
    print("Report ID = %s" % extract_id)
    time.sleep(polling_delay)
    return extract_id

login(s)
launchReport(s)
```

`Output:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE SIMPLE_RETURN SYSTEM 
"https://qualysapi.qualys.com/api/2.0/simple_return.dtd">
<SIMPLE_RETURN>
  <RESPONSE>
    <DATETIME>2018-02-01T16:00:14Z</DATETIME>
    <TEXT>New report launched</TEXT>
    <ITEM_LIST>
      <ITEM>
        <KEY>ID</KEY>
        <VALUE>16441920</VALUE>
      </ITEM>
    </ITEM_LIST>
  </RESPONSE>
</SIMPLE_RETURN>
```

`Traceback:`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    launchReport(s)
  File "test.py", line 22, in launchReport
    extract_id = etree.XML(r).find('.//VALUE')
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3209, in lxml.etree.XML 
(src/lxml/etree.c:80823)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1870, in 
lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/etree.c:121231)
ValueError: can only parse strings
```

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to parse the response object instead of the data in the response. Change `etree.XML(r)` to `etree.XML(r.text)`.

Comment: Ahhh, yeah, makes sense. But, when I do that I get the following error: `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

Comment: Save your API call to file: `with open('tmp.xml', 'w') as f: f.write(r.text)` then parse with `etree.parse('tmp.xml')`

Comment: @Parfait this technically doesn't error out anymore, but I need to return what's inside the `<VALUE>` tag. I.e. `16441920`. The output I am getting is `Report ID = <Element VALUE at 0x1ae3098>`. Apologies if that was not clear before.

Comment: Use .text property: `etree.parse('tmp.xml').find('.//VALUE').text`